# How to implement subscription plan restrictions? (php)

Tags: php, laravel-5, subscription, restrictions

Let's say we have a simple SAAS that offers two types of plans. For example, in the cheapest plan you can create 20 lists at maximum and in the next plan you can create up to 50 lists. This is just one feature of the pricing model. Assuming the pricing model is based on 4-5 different features for each plan, what would be a good practice to check and enforce those restrictions?

I guess, the (messy) way would be to add a bunch of 'ifs' in different points, eg: if $user->plan->limitReached, do this etc.

Maybe another approach would be to throw some kind of events on user actions and handle the checks in a more 'centralized' way?
What are your thoughts on this scenario? Any suggestions would be appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: In general do not code such limits, use a configuration catalog instead. Apart from that: this is not a question that is well suited for the Q&A style used on this site since answers would hold personal preferences.

Comment: Yeah I guess this is not the most suitable place for this kind of question but I didn't get any answers elsewhere (reddit & laracasts). Thank you for your response though.

Comment: I would use some kind of ACL where you simply check `$acl->isAllowed('resource', 'privilege');`

Comment: I'm facing the same situation, and I'd give a try using Gate or authorizes(), but still feeling like mixing things up with my app domain. I found [this package](https://github.com/theseanstewart/Plan-Config) and it looks like I'll be able to get a clean solution for now.

Comment: @nteath I finally [got it implemented](https://github.com/timegridio/timegrid/commit/c2c8a767881fa7cb9b9fe0127d480e3a6a612fc0). Hope this helps for some guidance.

Comment: @alariva Thanks for the help. Your suggestion helped me get started

Comment: I will send a PR today, meanwhile you can use [my fork](https://github.com/alariva/Plan-Config), note that I have added a repositories parameter in my composer.json and specified `dev-patch` for version.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel 5.3 has a feature called [Policies](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authorization#generating-policies).

With those, you can create complex logic to allow or deny a request or anything, really, to the user.

It's the official Laravel-way to authorize a user action.

It also allows you to declutter your user models and controller classes and re-use code.